# Which javascript UI framework is my bet for cross platform/browser performance

Tags: user-interface, javascript, javascript-framework

I am looking for what my well be described as the holy grail.  A javascript UI framework which works reliably on both desktop and mobile browsers. In my case the most important are Internet explorer (7-9), Chrome and Android.

I have been doing some experiments with Jquery mobile, and found that while it looks great in Chrome it is really clunky and behaves unpredictably on internet explorer (versions 7-9). I was also surprised at how flickery and jerky it is on android honeycomb's browser.

At this point I am wondering if it is worth persisting with jquery-mobile, and I want to find out what frameworks others are using, and if there is currently such a thing as a reliable cross platform javascript ui framework.

Answer (score 0):

I still maintain that the jQuery mobile framework is the best out there. There aren't a ton of choices but I'd stick with the jQuery mobile as I have used it for many projects. There are always workarounds for issues with the framework and there is an awesome community for support and fixes when you need them!

It's great!